# Select nth element in data frame by factor

Tags: r

I've got a dataframe with a text column `name` and factor `city`. It is ordered alphabetically firstly by `city` and then `name`. Now I need to get a data frame which contains only nth element in each `city`, keeping this ordering. How can it be done in a pretty way without loops?

I have:

```
name    city
John    Atlanta
Josh    Atlanta
Matt    Atlanta
Bob     Boston
Kate    Boston
Lily    Boston
Matt    Boston
```

I want a function, which returns n'th element by `city`, i.e., if it is 3rd, then:

```
name    city
Matt    Atlanta
Lily    Boston
```

It should return `NULL` for `name` if it is out of range for the selected `city`, i.e., for 4th:

```
name    city
NULL    Atlanta
Matt    Boston
```

Using only base R please?

Comment: Could you give a reproducible example? Say, show a short example dataframe similar to what you have and another showing what you want it to become?

Comment: with `plyr`: `ddply(yourdata, .(city), function(x, n) x[n,], n=10)` But what if you're selecting an `n` greater than the number of entries  for a city?

Comment: can this be done using dplyr?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In base R using `by`:

Set up some test data, including an additional out of range value:

```
test <- read.table(text="name    city
John    Atlanta
Josh    Atlanta
Matt    Atlanta
Bob     Boston
Kate    Boston
Lily    Boston
Matt    Boston
Bob     Seattle
Kate    Seattle",header=TRUE)
```

Get the 3rd item in each city:

```
do.call(rbind,by(test,test$city,function(x) x[3,]))
```

Result:

```
        name    city
Atlanta Matt Atlanta
Boston  Lily  Boston
Seattle <NA>    <NA>
```

To get exactly what you want, here is a little function:

```
nthrow <- function(dset,splitvar,n) {
    result <- do.call(rbind,by(dset,dset[splitvar],function(x) x[n,]))
    result[,splitvar][is.na(result[,splitvar])] <- row.names(result)[is.na(result[,splitvar])]
    row.names(result) <- NULL
    return(result)
}
```

Call it like:

```
nthrow(test,"city",3)
```

Result:

```
  name    city
1 Matt Atlanta
2 Lily  Boston
3 <NA> Seattle
```

Comment: beat me to it. @sashkello please try to be as specific as possible in your initial questions, especially when using extra packages is out of the question since so much of R is built on user contributed features.

Answer (score 3):

A `data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(test)

# return all columns from the subset data.table
n <- 4
DT[,.SD[n,] ,by = city]
##      city name
## 1: Atlanta   NA
## 2:  Boston Matt
## 3: Seattle   NA

# if you just want the nth element of `name` 
# (excluding other columns that might be there)
# any of the following would work

DT[,.SD[n,] ,by = city, .SDcols = 'name']


DT[, .SD[n, list(name)], by = city]


DT[, list(name = name[n]), by = city]
```

Comment: selectedCol = "city",  step= 4 , DT[,.SD[seq(1,.N,by=step),] ,by = selectec_Col]  also work even I don't understand if it's better or worse

Answer (score 2):

You can use `plyr` for this:

```
dat <- structure(list(name = c("John", "Josh", "Matt", "Bob", "Kate",
```

"Lily", "Matt"), city = c("Atlanta", "Atlanta", "Atlanta", "Boston", 
"Boston", "Boston", "Boston")), .Names = c("name", "city"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))

```
library(plyr)

ddply(dat, .(city), function(x, n) x[n,], n=3)

> ddply(dat, .(city), function(x, n) x[n,], n=3)
  name    city
1 Matt Atlanta
2 Lily  Boston
> ddply(dat, .(city), function(x, n) x[n,], n=4)
  name   city
1 <NA>   <NA>
2 Matt Boston
>
```

There are plenty of other options too using base R or `data.table` or `sqldf`...