# more efficient way to take every nth element in data.table by factors

Tags: r, data.table

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850386/select-nth-element-in-data-frame-by-factor) has discussed about doing it for data frame. I want to do a little more complicated than that:

```
dt <- data.table(A = c(rep("a", 3), rep("b", 4), rep("c", 5)) , B = rnorm(12, 5, 2))
dt2 <- dt[order(dt$A, dt$B)] # Sorting
# Always shows the factor from A
do.call(rbind, by(
  dt2, dt2$A,
  function(x) data.table(A = x[,A][1], B = x[,B][4])
              )
        )
#This is to reply to Vlo's comment below. If I do this, it will return both row as 'NA'
    do.call(rbind,
        by(dt2, dt2$A, function(x) x[4])
      )
# Take the max value of B according to each factor A
do.call(rbind, by(dt2, dt2$A,
                  function(x) tail(x,1))
                  )
        )
```

What are more efficient way(s) to do this with `data.table` native functions?

Comment: You should only use `order` within `data.table` scope when you want to sort in decreasing order. In your case, instead of creating `dt2`, just do `setkey(dt, A, B)` and work with your original data

Comment: @DavidArenburg, or if you really want to preserve the original data. Also, there's a new function `setorder` in 1.9.3, with which you can order *by reference* in any order :).

Comment: @Arun, you guys keep to amaze me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `data.table`, you can refer to columns as if they are variables within the scope of dt. So, you don't need the `$`. That is,

```
dt2 = dt[order(A, B)] # no need for dt$
```

is sufficient. And if you want the 4th element of `B` for every group in `A`:

```
dt2[, list(B=B[4L]), by=A]
#    A        B
# 1: a       NA
# 2: b 6.579446
# 3: c 6.378689
```

Refer to @Vlo's answer for your second question.

From the way you're using `data.table`s, it seems like you've not gone through any vignettes or talks. It'd be helpful for you to check out the [Introduction and the FAQ vignettes](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) or [tutorials from the homepage](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org); especially, [Matt's @user2014 tutorial](http://user2014.stat.ucla.edu/files/tutorial_Matt.pdf) amidst others.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I went through the FAQ, but did not get it much. The point about applying `list()` command to `j` you showed here clarified lot of things for me.

Comment: @Arun, why not just `setkey(dt, A, B)`? As the only reason he created `dt2` was in order to sort `dt`

Comment: That's true. I have just got that from Matt's presentation that @Arun pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

First statement makes no sense to me, here is the second

```
# Take the max value of B according to each factor A
dt2[, list(B=max(B)), by=A]
```